# Highcharts: negative value in hebrew

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, right-to-left, negative-number

I'm using Highcharts with hebrew names. When I have negative values, the tooltip display the minus sign (-) on the right side.

[tooltip display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5erM8.png)

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Column chart with negative values'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'שרה',
        data: [5, 3, -4, 7, -2]
    }, {
        name: 'שי',
        data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
    }]
});
```

});

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0rLyfam/)

How to display it on the left side?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use tooltip.formatter to customise what it is displayed inside the tooltip. Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/r0rLyfam/2/

Comment: Thank you morganfree! Isn't there a most simple way?

Answer (score 1):

check out this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/mooioom/upcq96k5/

A general useful tip for all numeral-direction-problems in RTL languages is to 
apply `direction:ltr` and `display:inline-block` on the element which is wrapping the number.

in this specific case you also need to add `tooltip : { useHTML:true }` on the highcharts object in order for highcharts to render the tooltip using html (and not svg) ...